# Upload Media files to MongoDB from Node.js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I have a MEVN Stack app. This requires to upload media files to the database. From the client-side, I am posting a multipart type form which will send the file to the server through Axios. I don't know how to store that in the MongoDB database and retrieve the same.

Comment: You might want to check this article: https://alexmarquardt.com/2017/03/02/trade-offs-to-consider-when-storing-binary-data-in-mongodb/

Comment: Are you sure you want to store the files inside of MongoDB or you are just looking to store them on the file system and store the URL's in the database?

Comment: I have some photos and videos that I want to store and retrieve from MongoDB in a web app that I'm creating. That's why I was looking for a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is creating an API in node.js to handle uploaded file. (You can use express.js to make your life easier if you are not already using it)

In Vue.js create a component to upload a file and store the files in the file system on the server might be in a folder that is accessible through the web server (like in a public folder).

Finally, save the URL to access the file in MongoDB so, you can reference it later. You can google for tutorials on this, an example is [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/uploading-files-and-images-with-vue-and-express-2018ca0eecd0).